# How to correctly break a greedy regex on the first matching condition?

Tags: regex

In this http://regex101.com/r/aT8yM3/4 example, I would like to match the "Title1" key.

```
Case1 1: Delimited with an empty line

 ***************************************
 * Some preambule...
 * Title1 : Some multi-line text
 *          Here the second line
 * Title2 : Some other text
 ***************************************

Case1 2: Delimited an empty line

 ***************************************
 * Some preambule...
 * Title1 : Some multi-line text
 *          Here the second line
 *
 * Title2 : Some other text
 ***************************************

Case1 3: Delimited with a separator

 ***************************************
 * Some preambule...
 * Title1 : Some multi-line text
 *          Here the second line
 ***************************************
```

For both cases I should get this string:

```
Some multi-line text
 *          Here the second line
```

The regex I used is:

```
/
^.*?Title1\s*:\s*     # I want to get the key "Title1"
((?:\n|.)+?)           # Which can be a multi-line string
^(?:
   .*Title2\s*:(*SKIP)       # Until the line that contains 'Input : '
|
   [^*]\*\n(*SKIP)           # Or until the a blank line
| 
   ^[^*]\*+(*SKIP)           # Or until a separator
)
/gmx
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. It seems the structure

```
(cond1|cond2|cond3)
```

Evaluates all conditions. I would like to break the regex at the first successful condition with something like `(*SKIP)` or `(*PRUNE)` but I didn't find the way to do it.

I also tried to put it diffently:

```
(?|
   ^.*?Title1\s*:\s*     # I want to get the key "Title1"
   ((?:\n|.)+?)          # Which can be a multi-line string
   ^.*Title2\s*:         # Until the line that contains 'Input : '
|
   ^.*?Title1\s*:\s*     # I want to get the key "Title1"
   ((?:\n|.)+?)          # Which can be a multi-line string
   ^[^*]\*\n             # Or until the a blank line
|
   ^.*?Title1\s*:\s*     # I want to get the key "Title1"
   ((?:\n|.)+?)          # Which can be a multi-line string
   ^[^*]\*+              # Or until a separator
)
```

Comment: Why you don't want to capture the following `*` after `...` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It doesn't matter, I can either capture it

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/aT8yM3/2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.*Action\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=Input|Output|\s+\*)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dP9rO4/11

Comment: I rewrote my question